# Sql server trigger to update values based on primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my query.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON CUSTOMERS
    AFTER INSERT
    AS

    if exists ( select * from CUSTOMERS t 
        inner join inserted i on i.name<>t.name or i.age<>t.AGE or i.address<>t.address or i.salary<>t.SALARY
        and i.id = t.id)
    begin
        UPDATE c SET c.name = i.name,    c.age = i.age     c.address=i.address FROM CUSTOMERS as c INNER JOIN inserted i ON c.id = i.id 
    end   go
```

In this update statement i want to update all the columns and rows whose id is matching.but when i try to insert old row is getting updated where id matches and a new record is getting inserted

Comment: What is the issue you are facing here?

Comment: how to update values?... values will come dynamically

Comment: What do you mean by "(all inserted names)", etc when the `IF` has already established that the names, ages, addresses and salaries are equal to existing values? It looks like you've got some serious modelling/normalization issues here.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. It basically says "If my data is the same then make it the same"

Comment: updated the code...

Comment: @adams . . . You should be doing this using `merge` rather than a trigger.

Comment: Is id the primary key column of the table CUSTOMERS?

Answer (score 0):

If I am right you can try the update with inner join as shown below.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON CUSTOMERS
AFTER INSERT
AS
if Exists (select * from CUSTOMERS t 
    inner join inserted i on i.id=t.id
    and i.age=t.AGE 
    and i.[address]=t.[address]
    and i.salary=t.SALARY
    and i.id <> t.id)
begin
 UPDATE c
 SET c.name = i.name,  
     c.age = i.age
     --...and so on
 FROM CUSTOMERS as c
 INNER JOIN inserted i ON c.id <> i.id              
end
```

Comment: P.S - This answer is just for what you can do and need your effort as the question need more clarification.

Comment: what i am tyring is.. when i try to insert a new row in a table and if that values exists in that table then based on id i want to update that rows